# Set Pie Charts To Not Show 0%

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is there a way to have a pie chart only show labels if there value is at least 1%?  I have a dataset that returns about 20 results and I total the set then add a percentage to each individual return.  So sometimes there will be 0% and it just junks up the graph and makes it difficult to read.  Is there a standard way or custom function that can disable 0% from showing?

Let me add some knowledge here as well.  My data is set-up so that the data returned from my dataset is displayed in column 1 and 2 - then in column 3 is a percentage that divides the data in column 2 by the total column.  So it looks like this:
Microwave   42    30%
Stove       100   70%
Total       142   100%

How could it be achieved with data in this format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past I've solved this by using a custom expression in the Series Label:

[image]

Where I essentially display an empty string where the data % is under a certain level, something like:

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!MyValue.Value) / Sum(Fields!MyValue.Value, "ChartDataSet") < 0.01
    , ""
    , "#PERCENT{P0}")
```

Where `Sum(Fields!MyValue.Value) / Sum(Fields!MyValue.Value, "ChartDataSet")` is simply working out the % value of that particular group.

**Edited to add:**

Actually, thinking about this a bit more, you can use the **Chart Series** -> **Label** -> **Visible** property to control this; set the property as something like:

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!MyValue.Value) / Sum(Fields!MyValue.Value, "ChartDataSet") < 0.01
    , False
    , True)
```

[image]

Maybe this is a slightly neater way of achieving the same thing.

Comment: This is overkill, in my opinion. You can set the zero value in the Number section of the Series Label Properties to be (none)

Comment: That's certainly useful in some circumstances, but the requirement is to hide under 1%, so something like 0.5% should be hidden, but it's also non-zero so your suggestion won't work in that particular case. To be fair I haven't specifically tested your particular suggestion.

Comment: If that is the requirement, then yep, very true. I took "Is there a standard way or custom function that can disable 0% from showing?" to be the requirement.

Comment: I get this error when I try that:
The Label expression for the chart 'Chart1' uses an aggregate function on a report item.  Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers.

Comment: @user3056839, yep, I think it's all in the way one reads the question - agree that in your case this approach would be a bit much.

Comment: @user2954053, it sounds like you're using a reference to a report item, i.e. `ReportItems!...` when my example expression is specifically looking at a Dataset field, i.e. `Fields!...`. This approach cannot reference the items from textboxes, you need to use the underlying data.